# Powershell [get-help] have no examples?

Tags: powershell

I m asking a very simple question here:

Do you guys get any examples inside powershell when using `get-help xxxxx -full` ?

I was watching a course on youtube, the guy from powershell team runs `get-help xxxx -full` and got lot of examples. I tried on ver2 and ver 4 both got no example at all. then i run `update-help` still  got nothing....

So just wondering if any of you has the same issue ?

Comment: Did your run update-help from an elevated session?

Comment: Yes, I run it as admin

Comment: What command did you run it against?

Comment: any command with `get-help`,  like `get-help get-childitem -full`

Comment: I didnt find why but i fixed it....I removed ps4 back to ps2 and re-installed it again. did a update-help, now i see all examples.....

Answer (score 0):

The following command will provide you with examples, but it will do so in your default browser:

get-help xxxxxx -Online